# Dojo Button doesn't render inside ContentPane

Tags: javascript, button, dojo, dijit.form

I want to have a button inside a ContentPane but I can't get it rendering. I have the same code for display the button inside a ContentPane and outside everything, in the body. The first one doesn't get rendering and the second one does, so it doesn't display the correct way and it doesn't fire events. The code for the button is:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"  data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconTask', onClick:function(){ console.debug('clicked simple') }">Simple</button>
```

And the code:

```
<body class="claro">
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconTask', onClick:function(){ console.debug('clicked simple') }">Simple</button>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuBarItem">
            <span>Sesión</span>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu">
                <div id="btnLogout" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="">Salir</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true" id="borderContainer">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'left'" style="width: 15%;" id="leftPane">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">
                <input id="agentFilter">
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="peopleTreePane" style="height: 90%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center'">
            <div id="appCenterTabContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center'">
                <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" title="Visitas" href="" id="visitasPanel">
                    <div>
                    <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
                        data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconTask', onClick:function(){ console.debug('clicked simple') }">
                        Simple
                    </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" title="Logs" href="" id="logsPanel">
                    <div id="gridLogs" class="appGrid" style="height: 20em;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the empty `href` attribute on your ContentPane is confusing Dojo's parser. You don't need that attribute unless you want the ContentPane to load its content from the server.

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" title="Visitas" href="" id="visitasPanel">
                                                          <!-- ^ remove this -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing height style property for borderContainer widget.

Cheers, 
kiuma